# Raspberry camera with opencv, measure brightness

Tags: opencv

I want to  build a camera with my Raspi.
It should take picture whenever a face is detected.
But it should give a warning when the brightness is too low for a good picture.
Does anybody know a simlpe way for that?
Right now I'm using a USB camera, but have also a Raspi camera at hand in the case it's easier with this.
Cheers
Florian

Comment: This question is so vague. A simple search on the internet will provide plenty of tutorial to achieve your goals. Here is a link to a popular raspberry pi tutorial for face detection/ recognition https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/25/raspberry-pi-face-recognition/